# How to call index number of function array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following list of functions:

```
var functions = {
                    blah: function () {
                        alert("blah");
                    },
                    foo: function () {
                        console.log("foo");
                    }
                };
```

I am now trying to access a specified index of the `functions` array, however I'm only getting undefined.

So `console.log(functions[0]);` returns undefined.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and instruct me on how to call a specified index of a function array in javascript? I need to cycle sequentially through the array, so need to call it by position number rather than name.

Comment: functions is an object, not an array.

Comment: `functions` is an object, not an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an array. It is an object.

You simply call it like this:

```
functions.foo();
```

or

```
functions.blah();
```

If you want to have an array of functions, your syntax would look something like this:

```
var functions = [{
    blah: function () {
        alert("blah");
    }
}, {
    foo: function () {
        console.log("foo");
    }
}];
```

You would call it like this:

```
functions[0].blah();
```

You can even do this:

```
var functions = [alert("blah"), console.log("foo")];

functions[0];
functions[1];
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/donal/29r8sthd/1/

Comment: OP said, he/she does not want to call it by function name.

Comment: OP also said that an object literal is an array.